# Show this set is a two-dimensional manifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

The set is $S:=\{ x \in \Bbb{R^3}:x_1^2+e^{-x_2}+x_3=5\}.$ We need to show that for every point $x\in S$, there is an open $U$ containing $x$, and an open $V\subset\Bbb{R^2}$, and a diffeomorphism $h:U\to V$ such that the following condition is satisfied $$h(U\cap S)=V\cap(\Bbb{R^2}\times{0})=\{y\in V:y_{3}=y_2=0\}.$$

The set is equivalent to those points where $f(x,y,z)=x_1^2+e^{-x_2}+x_3-5$ intersects the horizontal axis, and I suppose we can assume that every $x$ in $S$ is contained in some open set $U$. How can we find the appropriate diffeomorphism $h$?

Comment: It is easier to show that the Jacobian of $x_1^2 + e^{-x_2} + x_3 - 5 = 0$ is non-zero for all $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Then $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence in particular a 2-dimensional manifold. I am not sure however whether you are allowed to prove it in this way?

Comment: I would like to understand the definition first of all, but I'm interested in other solutions as well.